# Web component inheriting parent styles even with all: initial set

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

### MVCE

You can execute this code snippet:

```js
const a = document.createElement("div");

// display big red rectangle in top left
a.style.position = "absolute"; a.style.left = "10px"; a.style.top = "10px";
a.style.background = "red";
a.style.color = "green";
a.style.fontSize = "large";
document.body.appendChild(a);

// attach shadow root
a.attachShadow({mode: 'closed'}).innerHTML = `
      <style>
        :host {
          all: initial;
          display: block;
        }
      </style>

      <p>
        A paragraph element which should not inherit any styles from its parent webpage (outside the shadow DOM).
      </p>`;
```

### Description

I have copied the shadow root section verbatim from [lamplightdev](https://lamplightdev.com/blog/2019/03/26/why-is-my-web-component-inheriting-styles/), but the same code is also given on various Stack Overflow threads. Due to this code, the `<p>` element is NOT supposed to inherit any styles from its parent body.

### Problem

You can run the code snippet to see that the paragraph element appears green with large font size which is unexpected because I have set `:host { all: initial; }`.

In DevTools I can also see that the paragraph element is showing style rules that are "inherited from div" which is outside my web component.

### **Question**

I want my web component to not inherit parent page styles, yet why is it doing so?

Comment: `border` is not an inherited property. Inheritance is meant to trickle into shadowDOM, and thanks heaven it does.

Comment: You have no `border` set anywhere in your code. What are you talking about there? Ditto with `color`. The only CSS properties getting set are on the style attribute of the `div` that is the shadow root, and those are `position`, `bottom`, `right`, `width`, `height`, and `background`. Then you set `display` via the `innerHTML`.

Comment: Something weird going on....``:host{all:initial}`` does not reset (which should reset according to the docs), but targeting an element inside the shadowRoot does reset: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/6u1e4m3y/

Comment: @connexo The border comment was part of the code I copied verbatim from the linked website. My bad I forgot to change it.  I hope - apart from it - the rest of the point of my question is clear.

Comment: @HereticMonkey ditto on comment above.

Comment: Not really clear; perhaps you can update the snippet so it has some CSS that is then inherited by the web component? I think that would make it clearer than having people try and take your code and run it in their consoles.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thank you, I have updated the code snippet. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 4):

You **can** use `:host`.

But since it has lower Specificity, you have to force it with `!important`

```html
:host {
  all: initial !important;
}
```

Straight [from](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7249) Apple's lead Web Components engineer:

[image]

```js
const a = document.createElement("div");
      a.style.background = "red";
      a.style.fontSize   = "large";
      a.style.color      = "green";

document
  .body
  .appendChild(a)
  .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
  .innerHTML = `<style>
                  :host { all: initial !important }
                </style>
                Content which should not inherit any styles`;
```

Notes:

- `open` or `closed` shadowRoot has nothing to do with CSS;
  only use `closed` when you 100% understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `:host` selector is a wrong way to **stop inheritance**. What you are essentially saying is reset my CSS style for the `div` element and then apply - `position`, `background`, `color` and `fontSize` to my `div`. Since `color` by default inherits, it gets applied to `<p>` tag within the `shadowDOM`. Imagine like - first inheritance is getting applied to host `div` and then overriding host element `div` with the specified properties.

The correct solution is to not use `:host` selector and instead directly apply the styles to the `<p>` tag as:

```
<style>
  p {
    all: initial;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This is interesting but how would you prevent all inheritance to the component. Apply to * selector?